# Rest API - GET request returns a 404 error and as a response 0 with an existing account_id

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

I am implementing a Rest API.
It turns out that when using Postman I send a GET request to a route which receives as a parameter account_id = 100

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/balance?account_id=100`

`ID 100` exists but postman keeps returning 404 error with return "0".
I am using Laravel 8 and I think my problem is in the `Handler`. I show you the `BalanceController` controller and also the `Handler` class.

BalanceController:

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Account;
    
class BalanceController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $accountId = $request->input('account_Id');
        $account = Account::findOrFail($accountId);
        
        return $account->balance;
    }
}
```

**Handler.php class register Method**

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
        return response()->json('0',404);
    });
}
```

The idea is that when I make this request, I will return the balance of said ID with the response 200, I repeat the ID = 100 exists since I create it by POST request at another time with the logic in another controller.

api routes.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/reset', [App\Http\Controllers\ResetController::class, 'reset']);
Route::get('/balance', [App\Http\Controllers\BalanceController::class,'show']);
Route::post('/event', [App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'store']);
```

Comment: Please show your `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php`. Also show whats the output of `php artisan route:list | grep api`

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Comment: There modify the question showing the routes

Comment: I don't use routes / web.php. It's just a Rest API

Comment: Are you aware you have a case discrepancy between the URL and the controller?  `account_id` !== `account_Id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you implement this in Laravel's way. In your api.php, change your route so that it accepts a parameter like below.

Notice that `{account_id}` is then replaced with the actual ID number when a program hits this API route.

```
Route::get('/balance/{account_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\BalanceController::class,'show']);
```

and then, in your show() function, Add a second parameter like below:

```
public function show(Request $request, $account_id)
{
    $account = Account::findOrFail($account_id);
    
    return $account->balance;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I could solve it like this, it worked!

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you could mark this as the right answer as well.